# Difference between byte pointer and byte managed pointer

Tags: c++-cli

What is difference between

```
BYTE* p;
```

and

```
BYTE^ p;
```

Does this declarations makes any difference in c++cli if there is any difference what is that?

thanks in advance

Comment: The first is a pointer to a byte, the second is a boxed byte.

Comment: is BYTE^ is similar to BYTE __gc * in managed extensions ?

Comment: I think so, but I've never used the old syntax. It's similar to `System::Object^` except you know it's a handle to a (single) byte: a boxed value that is strongly typed.

Comment: The proper name for the second declaration is "bug".  BYTE is a value type, forcing a reference to it requires the byte to be boxed.  Which is the most inefficient possible way you could ever manipulate a byte.  It is a wee bit sad that the C++/CLI compiler doesn't generate a warning for this.  The C++/CLI compiler no longer requires decorating a pointer, it can generate error messages from invalid usage from the language syntax.  Small odds you may need the `interior_ptr` keyword, it isn't very common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BYTE^ p` would give you a managed handle to a single, boxed byte. You can't do much with it (you can read it, and I'm not sure you can write it even in C++/CLI; you certainly can't in C#), and there is little interest over using the byte directly in its unboxed form.

`BYTE* p` on the other hand, is the classic pointer to a byte, which can be the first of an array (or even any byte within an array thereof).

`pin_ptr` can give you the latter from the former.